# How do I set focus in side an autocomplete textbox

Tags: wpf

I have downloaded 3rd party autocomplete textbox and referenced it in my project. I have 3 autocomplete textboxes FirstName, LastName, ReceiptNo. When the form loads I want the firstname to be in focus. How to achieve this.

I have tried several steps like

```
//Eventhandler while form loads
private void Page_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FirstName.Focus();
}
```

or

```
//Eventhandler while autocomplete textbox loads  
void FirstName_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FirstName.Focus();
}
```

I also tried creating a bool isvisible property and binding it to autocomplete FirstName textbox in Xaml but that does not works. Any help will be appreciated.

My xaml code is given below

```
<wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox  Style="{StaticResource AutoComp}" 
                          Height="32"
                          Canvas.Left="33"
                          ToolTip="First Name"
                          Canvas.Top="120"
                          Width="205"
                          Padding="10,5"
                          TabIndex="1001"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          Loaded="FirstName_GotFocus"                      
                          Watermark=""
                          IconPlacement="Left"
                          IconVisibility="Visible"
                          Delay="100"
                          Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue=''}" 
                          Provider="{Binding FirstNameSuggestions}">
    <wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Padding="5">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                               FontWeight="Bold" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox.ItemTemplate>
</wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox>

<Label Style="{StaticResource Devlbl}"
       Canvas.Left="250"
       Content="Last Name"
       Canvas.Top="90" />
    <wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox Style="{StaticResource AutoComp}"
                             Height="32"
                             ToolTip="Last Name"
                             Canvas.Left="250"
                             Canvas.Top="120"
                             Width="205"
                             Padding="10,5"
                             TabIndex="1002"
                             VerticalAlignment="Top"
                             Watermark=""
                             IconPlacement="Left"
                             IconVisibility="Visible"
                             Delay="100"
                             Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue=''}" 
                             Provider="{Binding LastNameSuggestions}">
        <wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Padding="5">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                   FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox.ItemTemplate>
    </wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox>
</Label>
<Label Style="{StaticResource Devlbl}"
       Canvas.Left="480"
       Content="Receipt No"
       Canvas.Top="90" />
    <!--<TextBox Canvas.Left="480"
             ToolTip="Receipt No"
             Canvas.Top="107"
             Width="205"
             MaxLength="10"
             TabIndex="1003"
             Style="{StaticResource CommonTextBox}"      
             Text="{Binding ReceiptNo,TargetNullValue=''}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <b:AllowableCharactersTextBoxBehavior RegularExpression="^[0-9]+$" MaxLength="10" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>-->
    <wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox Style="{StaticResource AutoComp}"
                             Height="32"
                             ToolTip="Receipt No"
                             Canvas.Left="480"
                             Canvas.Top="120"
                             Width="205"
                             Padding="10,5"
                             TabIndex="1002"
                             VerticalAlignment="Top"
                             Watermark=""
                             IconPlacement="Left"
                             IconVisibility="Visible"
                             Delay="100"
                             Text="{Binding ReceiptNo, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue=''}" 
                             e:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding IsFocused, Mode=TwoWay }"   
                             Provider="{Binding ReceiptIdSuggestions}">
        <wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Padding="5">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                   FontWeight="Bold">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox.ItemTemplate>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <b:AllowableCharactersTextBoxBehavior RegularExpression="^[0-9]+$" MaxLength="15" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt is very close. Try doing the following in the `Page_Loaded_1` event handler

`this.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));`

(Note - `MoveFocus` is a method on the Window class, it's not something you need to implement)

You should define your textboxes to have tab-indices. After the page loads, the TraversalRequest will give focus to the first tab-indexed control. If no tab indices are defined I believe it will give focus to the top of the UI hierarchy, so technically the main window would receive focus in that case.

For reference, here's an [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusnavigationdirection(v=vs.110).aspx) to all of the `FocusNavigationDirection` options.

Comment: Thanks for informing me about MoveFocus method and FocusNavigatgionDirection. I changed the code and its working fine.  I am not able to upvote your answer I do not have enough reputations. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code as shown below and its working fine. I added a cavas as container and placed my auto complete textbox inside the canvas.

```
    FocusNavigationDirection focusDirection = FocusNavigationDirection.Next;

        // MoveFocus takes a TraveralReqest as its argument.
        TraversalRequest request = new TraversalRequest(focusDirection);
        UIElement elementWithFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
        if (elementWithFocus != null)
        {
            elementWithFocus.MoveFocus(request);
        }
```